# What is the verb for "Glossary"?

Tags: verbs, nouns, expression-choice

Some software I am using has got the word "Glossarise" in it, which baffles me immensely. My spell checker hates it but googling for the word returns results for sites like Urban Dictionary but no reputable dictionaries or resources.

Since I am in the position where I work for the company that writes this software, I figured I'd suggest it gets fixed and replaced with an actual word.

In the software, the word is used to apply custom glossary entries to text on a page, following a process where you select the word or phrase and then click a button on a toolbar which is labelled as "Glossarise".

What is the verb for "Glossary"?

Comment: "create a glossary"? "add to glossary"?

Comment: In this context it's more like assigning a popup to a word or phrase corresponding to an entry that has already been added to the glossary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *[gloss](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gloss)*.

> to insert glosses on; annotate.
>   to place (a word) in a gloss.